# Image Right Edge Fade/Blur CSS

Tags: css, fade, blur

I have a simple CSS related question. How do I obtain the right end blur/fade as shown in the image?

[image]

Comment: `-webkit-mask-image`, but works only in Chrome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Two methods

Let's make this:

[image: Screenshot]

### 1. Using box-shadow

**Browser Compatibility:** IE 9 + for [box-shadow.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)

- Place appropriate `box-shadow` inset in the div
- The div is given left padding to line it's text up with the white part of the background (the [`box-sizing: border-box` essentially absorbs the padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) into the width)

#### Box-shadow example

```css
div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF4np.jpg) no-repeat;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding-left: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset -350px 0 100px 0 #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <a>Link</a>
</div>
```

### 2. Using multiple background images with a linear-gradient

**Browser Compatibility**: IE 9 + for [multiple background images](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds) / IE 10 + for [CSS linear gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) (IE 9 can be supported with an IE gradient filter or a partially transparent `.png`)

- The container div is given a linear-gradient background followed by the image background (separated by a comma)
- The div is given left padding to line it's text up with the white part of the background (the [`box-sizing: border-box` essentially absorbs the padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) into the width)

#### Gradient example

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 240px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 290px), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF4np.jpg) no-repeat;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding-left: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <a>Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: no longer works, the picture shows in front of the fade efect (chrome, edge)

Comment: @EgonStetmann. They both look fine to me? I fixed the broken CSS background images in my examples; maybe that was causing confusion.

Comment: oh, and for the gradient example you need to make sure the image is placed second in the background value. The first background (in this case the gradient) in the value will overlap the second (in this case the image), the second would then overlap a third background, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CSS gradient that goes from completely transparent to white and position it over the RHS of the image.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
```

Check which vendor prefixes apply to your target platforms.